# Warning: Error in <Promise>: Server denied you to change to the given directory in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to connect to an ftp server in r and want to download a file. It succeeds fully when I am using this code running offline.

```
url = "ftp://user:pswd@000.000.0.00/folder_name"
filenames <- getURL(url,ftp.use.epsv = FALSE,dirlistonly = TRUE)
userpwd <- "user:password"


filenames = paste(url,"/", strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]], sep = 
"") 
con = getCurlHandle( ftp.use.epsv = FALSE) 

download_ftp_file <- function(file_remote, file_output, credentials = 
"", 
                          curl = FALSE, verbose = FALSE, progress = 
"none") {

 # Check
if (!length(file_remote) == length(file_output))
 stop("Remote and output vectors need to be the same length...", call. 
= FALSE)

# Build mapping data frame
df_map <- data.frame(
file_remote = file_remote,
file_output = file_output,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Do
plyr::a_ply(
 df_map, 
 1, 
 download_ftp_file_worker, 
 credentials, 
 curl,
 verbose, 
 .progress = progress
)

# No return

}
```

It succeeds, but the same code when I use it in my shiny app, I get an error:

> Warning: Error in : Server denied you to change to the given
>   directory

How to solve this please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it ended up being that my ftp path was incorrect.

I pasted my ftp location into firefox and it returned that the address could not be found and I saw I was missing a backslash.